# Github Apps: Authorize & Request on applications doesn't return code parameter

Tags: github, github-api, github-app

I've created a Github app with the option "Request user authorization (OAuth) during installation".

When a user requests his admin to install the app, the admin accepts and gets back to the app. I then get a url like:

`http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback?code=a22757013d09ccc5f6ed&installation_id=18334019&setup_action=install&state=MYAPPSTATE`

BUT when the user Authorize & Request and he gets back to the app I only get a url like so:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback?setup_action=request&state=MYAPPSTATE
```

My question is, how to get Github to give me the code parameter so I can know which user has requested to install the github app ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the response I got from GitHub support:

The code parameter is only returned for authorization during installation. There isn't a way to generate one for the user who has requested an admin to approve, authorise and install.

As an organization owner/admin, you should see on the GitHub App review install page the user who has made this request during the application installation. You can also check the integration_installation_request.create logs in the organization to find the user who has requested the installation

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this has been fixed now https://github.com/pre-commit-ci/issues/issues/70#issuecomment-899129055